# Answer ratio trend stats for mods

Tags: feature-request, statistics, moderator-tools, beta-sites

Since the answer ratio (average number of answers per question) is one of the five health parameters mentioned in Area51 for beta sites, it would be great to have a historical trend graph for this value in the moderator statistics page.

I know these parameters are indicative, however it would be quite useful for mods to actually understand whether there are positive or negative trends in this regard.

Answer (score 7):

Based on @rene's query [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300678/295232), I was able to construct a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/query/1386266/answer-ratio-trend#graph) which simulates calculation of the answer ratio at various moments in the past. This is how it looks like for Skeptics:

[image]

With the built-in site switcher you can easily produce a graph for other sites in the network.

Comment: This looks very interesting! I tried to run it for tex.se, but get a time out error (`Line 0: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`). Is there any trick to avoid the error?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz probably Tex.SE is too large for this query to work. I'll try to have a look this weekend if I can make it more performant. Thanks for posting the bounty!

Comment: Would it help to restrict the query to a single tag?

Comment: You might look into if spooling records from PostWithDeleted  with just the columns you need into a #TempTable with an index on creationdate and deletiondate as those are your  biggest contributors to table/index scans.

Comment: @rene, thanks, that fixed it for Meta.SE: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1386266/answer-ratio-trend#graph TeX.SE is still too big though.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1387590/answer-ratio-trend-single-tag?tagName=bug#graph) is a version for a single tag on a site.

Comment: @Glorfindel Brilliant! Thanks a lot!